# How to remove zero entries inside a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array in MATLAB, lets say `cell_arr` and it has zero entries as well as non-zeros cell entries. For example:

```
cell_arr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {1x3 cell}, {1x3 cell}, {1x3 cell}, {1x3 cell}};
```

Can somebody please tell how to remove these zero entries from the `cell_arr` or, to find the indices of non-zero entries? Additionally, I want to avoid `for` loop for performing this job.

I already tried `find` function, however, `find` function is not applicable for cell arrays. I am wondering if there exists a single line statement/expression doing this job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no single line function. You have to combine some functionallity. 
The first line finds the zeros in your cell array, while the second line deletes those entries. Note the `()` parentheses i.s.o. `{}` for removal.

Try this:

```
idxZeros = cellfun(@(c)(isequal(c,0)), cell_arr);
cell_arr(idxZeros) = [];
```

Comment: Using the function `isequal(c,0)` avoids using the two tests `~iscell(c) && c == 0`

Comment: @Magla true, however I think this is easier to debug, as one should understand that whenever the first test fails the second test will not be executed.

Comment: @Nick: I see nothing hard to debug about `C_pruned = C(~cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,0), C))`...Still, +1 :)

Comment: @Nick I concur with Rody. `isequal(c, 0)` is just as easy to read/debug, and it's a more general solution than using `~iscell(c)`. If the cell array contains objects which are not cells and not zeros, `c == 0` might trigger an error.

Comment: @Nick: plus, what if there are not zeros in the cell, but null-characters (`char(0)`))? Your test would yield false positives, while `isequal` would be correct.

Comment: @EitanT & Rory, those are things I did not think off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell_arr(cellfun(@(x) ~x(1),cell_arr(:,1)),:) = []
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: This returns `cell_arr = {}(0x9)`

Comment: @Yunus. Thanks for the reply. No it is not working. It is giving Empty cell array. Answer given by Nick (first comment) is working.