# How do I find if a cell in a cell array contains a certain value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, find, cell-array

I have an array of cells `B`. I want to find if one of the cell contains a certain value, in this case `[1 1 1440 1920]`, and if so remove it.

I tried using:

```
ismember(mat2cell([1 1 1440 1920],1),B)
```

I got an error saying "Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of character vectors".

I thought that `mat2cell()` would give me a cell array. What am I doing wrong?

Is there an easier way to find this component if exist and remove it?

Comment: After looking around a bit more, it appears that this is *basically* a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18740802/52738) (the general solution is the same, just a different set of cell contents to search for), so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
B(cellfun(@(c) isequal(c, [1 1 1440 1920]), B)) = [];
```

The [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is applied to each cell of `B`, returning a logical index that is true anywhere the contents of a cell is equal to `[1 1 1440 1920]`. This index is then used to remove those cells.